# JDialog isn't rendering content with no error

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

```
package gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import listener.addHeaderListener;
import listener.removeHeaderListener;

public class headersGUI extends JDialog {
public JFrame GUI;
public JList headers;
public JTextField name;
public JTextField value;
public JButton addheader;
public JButton removeheader;
public headersGUI(JFrame initgui){
    super(GUI, "Headers");
    GUI=initgui;
    setup();
    layout();
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
}
public void setup(){
    headers=new JList(GUI.headervalues);
    headers.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    name=new JTextField(10);
    value=new JTextField(10);
    addheader=new JButton("Add");
    addheader.addActionListener(new addHeaderListener(this, GUI));
    removeheader=new JButton("Remove");
    removeheader.addActionListener(new removeHeaderListener(this, GUI));
}
public void layout(){
    JPanel bottompanel=new JPanel();
    this.getContentPane().add(headers, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    bottompanel.add(new JLabel("Name: "));
    bottompanel.add(name);
    bottompanel.add(new JLabel("Value: "));
    bottompanel.add(value);
    bottompanel.add(addheader);
    bottompanel.add(removeheader);
    this.getContentPane().add(bottompanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
}
```

that is the `JDialog` code, it just shows a blank `JDialog` i am using **JDK 1.5** on **mac OSX 10.5.8**

Comment: If you could provide SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) we should be able to help easier.

Comment: @xorty I didn't post that much and don't see a need for SSCCE since it is a small JDialog that don't contain so much

Comment: @italiano40: sorry to be harsh, but your statement immediately above is ignorant nonsense. If you knew where in your code the error lies, you'd have likely solved it. If you posted enough code for us to solve it, we'd have solved it. But you don't know this and no one here has obviously been able to solve it based on the scant information provided. Going through the motions of creating an SSCCE would help you isolate the problem and likely allow you to solve it too.

Comment: @Hovercraft so i should just post my whole codebase and lose my job to follow some SSCCE which i think works better for open source projects and not high stake cooperate projects, so yea no, your not being forced to help and i think you have help enough being rude

Comment: @italiano40: If you had read the SSCCE protocol, you'd see that it has nothing to do with "posting the whole codebase". Please read the link. [sscce](http://sscce.org) before jumping to conclusions. And what part of my statement above is false?

Comment: As to my not being forced to help, you are correct, but I have already invested quite a bit of time and effort going through your code and trying to understand your problem, and it's not asking too much of you to put more effort in so that the problem can in fact be solvable. Again, the problem is **not in the code you've posted**. So you'll either need to provide more information or code, or just quit this thread.

Answer (score 2):

The error isn't apparent in the code that you've posted, and this is why you are not getting answers. So now all we can do is guess, and my guess is that in all likelihood the data passed into the JDialog is deficient, possibly your passing in a different JFrame object from the one that is being displayed.  You should put debug statements into the code above and the code that uses the JDialog, such as:

```
public void setup(){
  headers=new JList(GUI.headervalues);  
  system.out.println(/* display some property of the GUI here */ );
```

And you should create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

By the way, what are JFrame#headervalues? That's not part of the JFrame API.

Comment: I can't post anymore code since it is a cooperate project and yes it isn't is part of the JFrame but i extended JFrame and added but as i said i can't post that code

Comment: Then I guess you're SOL. I still recommend that you pepper your code with println statements to try to isolate the error as that's the first step in debugging.